# Android Stack Trace contains (MT:xxxx) where I am expecting a line number

Tags: android, stack-trace

Following is an extract from a Stack Trace as reported under Crashes & ANRS on the Google Play Console. The code is obfuscated.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at au.com.fne.myomaps.RaceTrackActivity.c(MT:21193)
at au.com.fne.myomaps.ch.onClick(MT:1153)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:176)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
```

What does MT:xxxx refer to? `RaceTrackActivity.java` is only 1400 lines long.

Comment: MT:xxxx refer to lines of code in class level, which use lower level language, you can track the error, if you have android device which plugged to pc or virtual device, and test from your RaceTrackActivity.java, it usually force close the app, better test it in real device before publishing, happy coding!

Comment: @keronconk Thanks - that explains the high line number. RaceTrackActivity is my own Java code, so is there a way to get Java line numbers in the stack trace? (A compile setting?) Otherwise it is difficult to use crash dumps from published Apps(?)